# ember-cli-code-coverage mocha showing 0% coverage when there are tests

Tags: ember.js, code-coverage, ember-cli, ember-cli-code-coverage

I'm using [ember-cli-code-coverage](https://github.com/kategengler/ember-cli-code-coverage) with [ember-cli-mocha](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli-mocha).

When I run `COVERAGE=true ember test` I'm getting 0% coverage for statements, functions, and lines.

Yet, I have tests that are covering those sections. *Any I missing something in my setup?*

[image]

unit test file:

```js
beforeEach(function() {
    controller = this.subject();
});

it('sets selectedImage to null', function() {
    expect(controller.get('selectedImage')).to.eql(null);
});

describe('setCoverageTest', function() {
    it('sets selectedImage to true', function() {
        expect(controller.get('selectedImage')).to.eql(null);
        controller.setCoverageTest();
        expect(controller.get('selectedImage')).to.be.true;
    });
});
```

config/coverage.js:

```
module.exports = {
  excludes: ['*/templates/**/*'],
  useBabelInstrumenter: true
};
```

Comment: We use ember-cli-code-coverage@0.4.1  and ember-cli-mocha@0.14.4 with a wide variety of should and chai/expect style assertions. Our `config/coverage.js` only sets 'parallel' to true. What version are you running? Do you have a public link? I wonder if the excludes is interfering. Are you using pretender or any XHR stubbing by any chance? If so, be sure to exempt Another gotcha: ensure to exempt the '/write-coverage' path.

Comment: Did you use `this.passthrough('/write-coverage');` in your setup?
https://github.com/kategengler/ember-cli-code-coverage#create-a-passthrough-when-intercepting-all-ajax-requests-in-tests

Comment: We are also using the following properties in our coverage.js:   {parallel:false, coverageFolder : ‘pathtofolder’, reporters: [‘lcov’, ‘html’, ‘cobertura’]}.    It has been a while since I set this up but try adding these.

Comment: Are you using `ember-cli-content-security-policy >= 1.1.1`?

Answer (score 2):

Few well integrated tools to establish accurate code coverage for ember-cli apps exist. (something like Istanbul for everything in app/) We ended up avoiding ember-cli-blanket and writing a rudimentary istanbul 78 integration with testem. Basically, it calls the istanbul cli against the single JS file output by ember build. Imprecise but consistent. We've used in on [iDealeCasinos](https://idealecasinos.nl/online-casinos/casinoapps/) multiple times and it worked like a charm. Might be wise to give it a shot!